# Using KeyczarTool to create new keyset

Tags: encryption, filenotfoundexception, keyczar

Following the documentation noted in the [wiki](https://code.google.com/p/keyczar/wiki/KeyczarTool), I'm trying to use the [KeyczarTool](https://code.google.com/p/keyczar/) to generate new keyset. Anyone else come across this FileNotFoundException? The KeyczarTool.jar has rwx permissions and tried running via sudo.

From docs

```
Command Usage:
create --location=/path/to/keys --purpose=(crypt|sign) [--name="A name"] [--asymmetric=(dsa|rsa|ec)]
    Creates a new, empty key set in the given location.
    This key set must have a purpose of either "crypt" or "sign"
    and may optionally be given a name. The optional version 
    flag will generate a public key set of the given algorithm.
    The "dsa" and "ec" asymmetric values are valid only for sets
    with "sign" purpose.
```

Cmd:

```
$ java -jar KeyczarTool-0.71f-060112.jar create --location=/keys  --purpose=crypt -name="first key" --asymmetric=rsa
```

output:

```
org.keyczar.exceptions.KeyczarException: Unable to write to: /keys/meta 
    at org.keyczar.KeyczarTool.create(KeyczarTool.java:366)
    at org.keyczar.KeyczarTool.main(KeyczarTool.java:123)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /keys/meta (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:194)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:145)
    at org.keyczar.KeyczarTool.create(KeyczarTool.java:362)
    ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jbtule kindly pointed out you must create the keys dir first. But also include . before the slash.

Correct working command is: 
$ java -jar KeyczarTool-0.71f-060112.jar create --location=**./keys**  --purpose=crypt -name="first key" --asymmetric=rsa

Comment: well, or just  `--location=keys`

Answer (score 0):

With the current version of java keyczar the directory "keys" needs to be created first before running the program.

This is a known issue [KeyczarTool should create directories automatically](https://code.google.com/p/keyczar/issues/detail?id=115).

Comment: Thanks for the note, manually creating the dir is first thing I tried.